# Is it possible to setup a web app in Azure that connects to multilple on-premise databases?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I would like to setup an Azure web app that connects to different on-premise databases (same schema). These databases are in no way related to each other. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you want to use Hybrid Connections. See this article for how to set them up: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/integration-hybrid-connection-create-manage/

You'll still have to set up some kind of programmatic way of choosing which connection to use. You'd have to expand upon your scenario for me if you need more advice.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Basically, the setup would be I deploy a web app that multiple clients use, but those clients like to keep their data on their computers.

Comment: Yep, so hybrid connections and each time you onboard a new client, you set up a new hybrid connection.